# How to keep two objects to stick to each other while animate them?

Tags: animation, armature

[image: unforded]

I'm trying to make a miura-structure and this is it. 
[image]

But the problem is that since this movement is in spiral there is a gap between two units. How can I keep them sticking to each other while the movement? Thx in advance

Comment: Would basic parenting work?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos parenting between armatures? or objects? Could you tell me more precisely? Thank you.

Comment: Parenting is generally the most elementary way of attaching any two objects, object to armature or vice versa depending on what you want to achieve. I know little about animation so I can help much here, try to clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: My first instinct is that this requires a fair amount of math to maintain the connections between the objects as you animate them.  Blender can help you with *some* of the math if you arrange your armature correctly, and inverse kinematics can help with a few types of constraints, but it is not hard to come up with some origami that exceeds blender's tools and forces you to do some of the math yourself.  In truth, I suspect that there's a hill to overcome where you work hard to gain a great understanding of the math and it enables you to know if and how you can exploit blender's options.

Comment: I really want to add more images, but it says I need more reputation. Anyway, I made this model to be movable by one controller, and I used copy rotation. of the controller armature. that means each units moves exactly same way (But inverted). To maintain the columns to each other, some armature has to be rotated more than others. Thats what I figured out. and it needs some calculation... but I'm really bad at mathematics... Is there any solution, or function in Blender which I can use to solve this problem? :(